# Hardhat permission denied

Tags: node.js, npx, hardhat

## hardhat shows the below after running npx

npx hardhat init
sh: 1: hardhat: Permission denied

## I tried removing and installing the latest versions of node.js and still received the permission error after trying. Any assistance with setting up hardhat on WSL would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.